# How to write to an existing Excel file in Oracle Apex 22?

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

I was trying to write in Excel file that is already located on the server. I'm using Oracle  Apex 22. Is it avalibale?

I was trying to write in excel file. but I couldn't find the way I have been searching for a while.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible at all to *edit an existing excel file* but you can generate excel files with the API mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Generating a file is achievable on Apex with PL/SQL codes and existing generic packages. There are several ways to do so, you should decide which one is the best for your goals. You can for example use [Data Export Api](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aeapi/APEX_DATA_EXPORT.html#GUID-F195C61B-30DA-4462-93A3-465BCA6FCB78)

Comment: I don't need to Generate I need to modify an existing Excel file on the PC